# How can I increase Ubuntu hard drive space on AWS when resize2fs says there is nothing to do?

Tags: partitioning, aws

I've looked at a few tutorials, they say -

Step 1) run `df -h`

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.7G  6.1G  1.7G  79% /
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           787M  832K  787M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312
/dev/loop1       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6563
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2566
/dev/loop2       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1623
/dev/loop5       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1634
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2620
/dev/loop7       48M   48M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17029
/dev/loop6       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
/dev/loop8       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop9       48M   48M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17336
tmpfs           787M     0  787M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Step 2) run `lsblk`

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 24.4M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312
loop1         7:1    0 24.8M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6563
loop2         7:2    0 63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
loop3         7:3    0 55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566
loop4         7:4    0 55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2620
loop5         7:5    0 63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1634
loop6         7:6    0 67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop7         7:7    0   48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17029
loop8         7:8    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop9         7:9    0   48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17336
nvme0n1     259:0    0   30G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    8G  0 part /
```

Step 3) run `blkid`

```
$ blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="436cf32d-5e3d-46ca-b557-f870c8a25794" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="24ca9e81-01"
```

From here, every example online seems old, and every example has `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` as the example, and I can recall doing this in years past that I too had xvda1 as a Filesystem, but that is no longer the case in 2022 on a new machine

if I try to run `sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1` I get an error saying there is nothing to do

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 2096891 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I can see the 30G that I increased my volume to on `nvme0n1` but how do I get my OS to recognize the extra space now?

Answer (score 0):

Found this tutorial
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

ran the following commands

```
$ sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
CHANGED: partition=1 start=2048 old: size=16775135 end=16777183 new: size=62912479 end=62914527
```

was able to extend the size

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 24.4M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312
loop1         7:1    0 24.8M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6563
loop2         7:2    0 63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
loop3         7:3    0 55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566
loop4         7:4    0 55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2620
loop5         7:5    0 63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1634
loop6         7:6    0 67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop7         7:7    0   48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17029
loop8         7:8    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop9         7:9    0   48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17336
nvme0n1     259:0    0   30G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   30G  0 part /
```

determined the system type was ext4

```
$ df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4      7.7G  6.1G  1.7G  79% /
...
```

then was able to resize the partition using the given command

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/nvme0n1p1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 4
The filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p1 is now 7864059 (4k) blocks long.
```

disk % successfully dropped
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are very well.

About this exercise of resizing the file system in an EC2 Linux instance, I have some doubts.

When you ran `df -hT`, it shows the filesystem `dev/root`, type `ext4`

Then with the `lsblk` command, the `nvme0n1p1` partition is displayed whose size is equal to that of the volume.

My questions are: Would it be correct to have executed the command **sudo resize2fs /dev/root** instead of **sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1**, in which cases to execute each of them?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Kind regards.